# Higher Order Functions and Frame Stacking

Tags: python, higher-order-functions

I have been struggling to understand the concept of scoping the frames with a given higher order function being called recursively. An example I can give that I learnt in class is:

```py
def stack(default=lambda x: 0):
    def make(key, code):
        def take(attempt):
            if key == attempt:
                return code
            else:
                return default(attempt)
        return take, stack(take)
    return make
```

From what I understand, we are stacking our make function and upon calling take, it will evaluate the current and previous call to the make functions to see whether attempt matches one of our keys.

In a more general way, what is the concept behind this H.O.F manipulation and how do I make similar code from it?

```py
#doctests 
>>> make = stack()
>>> take1, make1 = make('key1', 'code1')  
>>> take2, make2 = make1('key2', 'code2')
>>> take3, make3 = make2('key3', 'code3') 
>>> take3('key1')
code1
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve. "how do I make similar code from it" can generally be answered by "change it slightly but not too much".

Comment: That is quite confusing sorry about that, just trying to understand the concept and maybe implement code of my own so that I can understand it better.

Comment: I believe that `def = lambda x: 0` should throw a syntax error, as `def` is a python keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that such a doubly nested inner function involving multiple closures is quite convoluted and hard to wrap one's head around. It can be helpful to take a look at what the dynamically defined inner functions actually look like in a particular case. For example, after running your sample code, the `take` functions will be equivalent to being defined like this:

```py
def take1(attempt):
    if 'key1' == attempt:
        return 'code1'
    else:
        return 0


def take2(attempt):
    if 'key2' == attempt:
        return 'code2'
    else:
        return take1(attempt)


def take3(attempt):
    if 'key3' == attempt:
        return 'code3'
    else:
        return take2(attempt)
```

Looking at this code, it's much easier to understand why `take3('key3') == 'code3'` or `take3('key1') == 'code1'`. You can see that the functions' `else` branches work as kind of a default-value cascade, enabling the correct key look-up, ultimately falling back to `0` if the key is not found.

To get acquainted with the concept of higher order functions, I would definitely recommend to start with something less complicated, e.g. a factory function that makes simple multiplying functions:

```py
def make_multiplier(n):

    def fn(x):
        return x * n

    return fn


multiply_by_3 = make_multiplier(3)
multiply_by_5 = make_multiplier(5)
```

```
>>> multiply_by_3(2)
6
>>> multiply_by_3(5)
15
>>> multiply_by_5(2)
10
>>> multiply_by_5(5)
25
```

These two dynamically generated functions will work exactly the same as if you defined them manually like

```py
def multiply_by_3(x):
    return x * 3


def multiply_by_5(x):
    return x * 5
```